# Fix link errors PHP, .HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made a website and I created .htaccess file and I am facing to a problem. After editing .htaccess file I renamed all the links according to .htaccess in the server that I am hosting the website. But in the localhost that is not working. Always shows the error 404. How should I fix this? I need to have same links in the server and the localhost. I am hosting in infinityfree.net site and my website link is thinu-tech-demo.rf.gd.

My .htaccess file:

```
php_value display_errors On
php_value mbstring.http_input auto
php_value date.timezone America/New_York
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(index|contact|registration)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)$ post.php?p_id=$1&p_title=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)$ category.php?cat_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I tried to fix this but I failed. I need to have same links in the server and the localhost. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that the AllowOverride directive is set to "All" in your Apache configuration file.

```
<Directory /path/to/your/website>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

It could also be that case t hjat the Apache mod_rewrite module is not enabled on your localhost. you will need to enable the mod_rewrite module by adding the following line to your Apache configuration file (located at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Also: please make sure that the rewrite rules are correctly formatted and that the file is saved with the correct encoding.

Comment: is the should be full like /xampp/htdocs/so/and/so ?

Comment: "/xampp/htdocs/your-website-folder" and then replace "your-website-folder" with the actual name of the folder that contains your website files. If you are unsure of the exact path to your website files, you can use the pwd command in a terminal window to find out the current working directory. For example, if you are in the htdocs directory, running pwd will print the full path to that directory.

Comment: I tried but not working. No CSS files are loading also.
https://i.imgur.com/otK9yHD.png

Comment: Make sure to replace "your-website-folder" with the actual name of the folder that contains your website files on your local machine, and "your-website.com" with the actual domain name of your live website, in your CSS ```<link href="/your-website-folder/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">```